# Create a spinner wheel for input from user

Tags: android

I have seen this spinner wheel which seems like a nice way to get input from users.

So I would like to find a way to create one. Though I have googled a lot I cant find good information about a way to create one. Just old code and old links that not work I have been able to find.

Down below is a image of what I want, but maybe with more alternatives (more wheels).

So the question is, how do I create one?

[image]

Comment: You can start by trying something and showing us what you've done so far. Any ways, there are a lot of Android GUI libraries, open source as well.

Comment: Yes, I haved tried github without any luck. And start coding with out any grahics or anything, whats the point? Somewhere there is a component like this I guess, I just cant find it. :)

Comment: you can visit this https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel,

Comment: Thanks @HetalUpadhyay I have checked and tested that, but without any luck of creating it like a spinning wheel as the image Iv attached

Answer (score 2):

Try to this way

```
import com.vijay.wheel.ArrayWheelAdapter;
import com.vijay.wheel.OnWheelChangedListener;
import com.vijay.wheel.OnWheelScrollListener;
import com.vijay.wheel.WheelView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {
        // TODO: Externalize string-array
        String wheelMenu1[] = new String[]{"name 1", "name 2", "name 3", "name 4", "name 5", "name 6","name 7","name 8","name 9"};
        String wheelMenu2[] = new String[]{"age 1", "age 2", "age 3"};
        String wheelMenu3[] = new String[]{"10", "20","30","40","50","60"};

        // Wheel scrolled flag
        private boolean wheelScrolled = false;

        private TextView text;
        private EditText text1;
        private EditText text2;
        private EditText text3;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);

                initWheel1(R.id.p1);
                initWheel2(R.id.p2);
                initWheel3(R.id.p3);

                text1 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.r1);
                text2 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.r2);
                text3 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.r3);
                text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.result);
            }

        // Wheel scrolled listener
        OnWheelScrollListener scrolledListener = new OnWheelScrollListener()
            {
                public void onScrollStarts(WheelView wheel)
                    {
                        wheelScrolled = true;
                    }

                public void onScrollEnds(WheelView wheel)
                    {
                        wheelScrolled = false;
                        updateStatus();
                    }
            };

        // Wheel changed listener
        private final OnWheelChangedListener changedListener = new OnWheelChangedListener()
            {
                public void onChanged(WheelView wheel, int oldValue, int newValue)
                    {
                        if (!wheelScrolled)
                            {
                                updateStatus();
                            }
                    }
            };

        /**
         * Updates entered PIN status
         */
        private void updateStatus()
            {
                text1.setText(wheelMenu1[getWheel(R.id.p1).getCurrentItem()]);
                text2.setText(wheelMenu2[getWheel(R.id.p2).getCurrentItem()]);
                text3.setText(wheelMenu3[getWheel(R.id.p3).getCurrentItem()]);

                text.setText(wheelMenu1[getWheel(R.id.p1).getCurrentItem()] + " - " + wheelMenu2[getWheel(R.id.p2).getCurrentItem()] + " - " + wheelMenu3[getWheel(R.id.p3).getCurrentItem()]);
            }

        /**
         * Initializes wheel
         *
         * @param id
         *          the wheel widget Id
         */

        private void initWheel1(int id)
            {
                WheelView wheel = (WheelView) findViewById(id);
                wheel.setAdapter(new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(wheelMenu1));
                wheel.setVisibleItems(2);
                wheel.setCurrentItem(0);
                wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
                wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
            }

        private void initWheel2(int id)
            {
                WheelView wheel = (WheelView) findViewById(id);
                wheel.setAdapter(new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(wheelMenu2));
                wheel.setVisibleItems(2);
                wheel.setCurrentItem(0);
                wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
                wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
            }

        private void initWheel3(int id)
            {
                WheelView wheel = (WheelView) findViewById(id);

                wheel.setAdapter(new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(wheelMenu3));
                wheel.setVisibleItems(2);
                wheel.setCurrentItem(0);
                wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
                wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
            }

        /**
         * Returns wheel by Id
         *
         * @param id
         *          the wheel Id
         * @return the wheel with passed Id
         */
        private WheelView getWheel(int id)
            {
                return (WheelView) findViewById(id);
            }

        /**
         * Tests wheel value
         *
         * @param id
         *          the wheel Id
         * @param value
         *          the value to test
         * @return true if wheel value is equal to passed value
         */
        private int getWheelValue(int id)
            {
                return getWheel(id).getCurrentItem();
            }
    }
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_bg">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.vijay.wheel.WheelView
            android:id="@+id/p1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        <com.vijay.wheel.WheelView
            android:id="@+id/p2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        <com.vijay.wheel.WheelView
            android:id="@+id/p3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/r1"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#000">
        </EditText>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/r2"
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#000">
        </EditText>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/r3"
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#000">
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:text="Your choice">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I saw this on githud also. Iv downloaded the classes. I should test it later. Thank you for reminding me! Hope it still works. :)

Comment: just try it and tell if you get any issue..and accept answer if it helped